# The constructor PdfPCell(Paragraph, Font) is undefined

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to set a font to a table cell with iText and I found this piece of code in a website:

```
Font myfont = new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC, 13);
PdfPCell cell8;
cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("hello"),myfont);
```

but I get this error: The constructor PdfPCell(Paragraph, Font) is undefined.

I know what the error means but I can't find another way to set the font.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell us on which web site you've found that piece of code? That way, we can inform the author of that page that he is wrong.

This won't work:

```
cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("hello"), myfont);
```

This will:

```
cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("hello", myfont));
```

But even that is incorrect, as it should be:

```
cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("hello", myfont));
```

`Paragraph` extends `Phrase` and when you pass a `Paragraph` to a `PdfPCell` it will be treated as a `Phrase` removing some specific properties of the `Paragraph`. This constructor creates a cell in **text mode**.

If you want to create a cell in **composite mode** (respecting the properties of the `Paragraph`), you need to do this:

```
cell8 = new PdfPCell();
cell8.addElement(new Paragraph("hello", myfont));
```

This is all explained in [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html), a free ebook you really should consult instead of web sites with examples that are wrong.